# What is the most efficient way to calculate Cosine Similarity across 6 million rows in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, sparse-matrix, large-data, recommendation-engine, cosine-similarity

I am currently facing a challenge with a Spark Dataframe that contains a single column named "items." This column is of type ArrayType of StringType. Each row in the dataframe represents the items associated with a particular user, resulting in approximately 6 million rows (users). My objective is to calculate the cosine similarity across all users, which essentially means finding the average cosine similarity for all pairs of users (which means 6,000,000*(6,000,000-1)/2 operations). However, I have been unable to find a solution that scales well for such a large dataset. I have attempted several approaches, but none of them have proven to be efficient. Here are the approaches I've tried:

1. Convert "items" to SparseVector, perform a self-join on the Dataframe, and then:

- Convert the result to an RDD and apply a User-Defined Function (UDF) to calculate the cosine similarity for all pairs. Finally, compute the mean.
- Or use the withColumn function to calculate the dot product, norms, and cosine similarity, and then calculate the average.

2. Combine the broadcasting of Spark and numpy functions with csr_matrix, as described in this article: https://medium.com/@rantav/large-scale-matrix-multiplication-with-pyspark-or-how-to-match-two-large-datasets-of-company-1be4b1b2871e.
3. Convert "items" to a DenseVector, then transform it into an IndexedRowMatrix, followed by a conversion to a CoordinateMatrix. Transpose the CoordinateMatrix, transform it back to an IndexedRowMatrix, and finally apply the IndexedRowMatrix.columnSimilarities() method to obtain the average.

Unfortunately, none of these approaches have scaled well with the quantity of data I have. Therefore, I have the following questions:

- How does your company tackle this problem? Are there any specific techniques or tools you use to handle such large-scale cosine similarity calculations?
- Are there alternative metrics that I could employ to assess the level of personalization in my item prediction system without requiring extensive computational resources?
- Is there a way to obtain an approximate value for the average cosine similarity, considering the limitations posed by the dataset's size?

Here's an example representation of my Dataframe:

```
items
['A', 'B', 'C']
['B', 'A', 'C']
['D', 'G', 'A']
['R', 'E', 'C']
['A', 'B', 'D']
```

Note that each array within the "items" column contains unique items, and the length of the arrays remains constant across all rows, i'm using pyspark.

Thank you all in advance for your valuable insights. I have been stuck on this problem for quite some time now and sincerely appreciate your responses.